# Need a regex with some validations for address field

Tags: javascript, regex, reactjs, regex-group

Allowed characters are [a-zA-Z0-9- /.#,] but

1. A blank must precede the pound sign.
2. There must not be a blank immediately before or after a dash.
3. Address must not begin with #, -, or /.
4. Address must not end with #, -, or /.
5. A slash must be surrounded in numerics.
6. Triple alphas are not allowed immediately following a numeric.
7. No single characters in the address field with the exception of N, S, E and W

So can any one suggest me to how to do this? Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please do edit you post and add what you tried? Where your regex failed exactly? Please read [how-to-ask-for-help-on-SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Also, it would be helpful adding a few example strings, indicating if they should pass or fail

Comment: Is a "blank" the same as a space? What do you mean by "single character"? Is it any character other than a whitespace that begins the string or is preceded by a whitespace character *and* is followed by a whitespace character or is at the end of the string? Or, should we replace the last two instances of "whitespace" in the last sentence by "non-word character"? I once had an address "4 Beckenham Lane". Presumably, that would not be permitted. Correct? What  about "2-1033 Shady Lane"?

Comment: I spent quite a bit of time preparing an answer. Is it too much to ask that you respond to the questions contained in my previous comment?

Answer (score 0):

- In regexes, it's usually easier to think of what's allowed, rather than what's forbidden. For instance:

  - Blank must precede the pound sign is better rephrased as "blank followed by pound sign is allowed", so one of the components will be: `( #)`
  - Must not start/end with #-/. is something like `^[a-zA-Z0-9]...[a-zA-Z0-9]$` (with a more generous pattern in the middle.
- If you're trying to validate addresses, as in postal addresses, consider whether this is a useful thing to do; there are [many surprising quirks with addresses](https://www.mjt.me.uk/posts/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-addresses/). What problem are you trying to solve? Is it worth rejecting some valid addresses in order to solve that problem?
- As others have commented, post what you've already tried and what didn't work?

  Use one of the interactive regex tools like [regex101](https://regex101.com/) to help, especially if you have examples of texts that should and shouldn't match.

Comment: Thanks for the help.."^[a-zA-Z0-9.,](?!.*?[^\na-z0-9.#, \/\-]{2}).*?[a-zA-Z0-9.,]$" I'm using this for Address must not begin with #, -, or / and Address must not end with #, -, or /. but still feeling trouble with other validations.

Comment: You don't need look-ahead for the "must not begin/end with #-/"; you can use something like `^[a-zA-Z0-9.,]([a-zA-Z0-9.,/#-]*[a-zA-Z0-9.,])?$`

Comment: Or, with the rules like the "space before #", something like `^[a-zA-Z0-9.,](([a-zA-Z0-9.,/-]| #)*[a-zA-Z0-9.,])?$`

Answer (score 0):

I have assumed a "blank" is a space and have not implemented requirement #7 because I do not understand what it means. Once #7 has been clarified I will attempt to amend the following regular expression.

```
^(?!#|.*[^ ]#)(?!.*(?: -|- ))(?!.*(?:\D\/|\/\D))(?!.*\d[A-Za-z]{3})(?![/-])[a-zA-Z0-9- /.#,]*(?<![#/-])$
```

[Start your engine!](https://regex101.com/r/r8PS23/1/)

Notice that the regex contains 5 *negative lookaheads* (`(?!...)`), three of which begin by consuming zero or more characters other than line terminators (`(?!.*...)`), and one *negative lookbehind* at the end (`(?<![#/-])` and no capture groups. The negative lookaheads implement the following assertions (in order):

- the pound sign, '#', must be preceded by a comma;
- a hyphen cannot be preceded or followed by a space;
- forward slashes must be preceded and followed by a digit; and
- digits may not be followed by 3 letters.
- the string may not begin with '/' or '-'

Note that the first of these requirements ensures the string does not begin with a pound sign.

Javascript's regex engine performs the following operations.

```
^                  : match beginning of string
(?!                : begin negative lookahead
  #                : match '#'
  |                : or
  .*[^ ]#          : match  0+ chars then char other than a space then '#'
)                  : end negative lookahead
(?!                : begin negative lookahead
  .*               : match 0+ chars other than newlines
  (?: -|- )        : match ' -' or '- '
)                  : end negative lookahead
(?!                : begin negative lookahead
  .*               : match 0+ chars other than newlines
  (?:              : begin a non-capture group
    \D\/           : match a non-digit followed by '/' 
    |              : or
    \/\D           : match '/' followed by a non-digit
  )                : end non-capture group
)                  : end negative lookahead
(?!                : begin negative lookahead
  .*               : match 0+ chars other than newlines
  \d[A-Za-z]{3}    : match a digit, then 3 letters
)                  : end negative lookahead
(?!                : begin negative lookahead
  [/-]             : match '/' or '-'
)                  : end negative lookahead
[a-zA-Z0-9- /.#,]* : match 0+ chars in char class
(?<![#/-])         : match '#', '/' or '-' in negative lookbehind
$                  : match end of string
```

Comment: I assume #7 is intended to be "no single _letters_ other than N, S, E and W", so for instance it should reject Avenue A, New York; or Franklin D Roosevelt Avenue/Drive/Street.